# Joining 4 tables resulting an empty result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables with this detail on each table

**deli_order Table**

```
order_code | code | plat_create_time | status
OC001        C001   2019-04-14    Success
OC002        C002   2019-04-14    Success
OC003        C003   2019-04-14    Success
```

**pg_order Table**

```
id |order_code | code | plat_create_time
1    OC001       C001   2019-04-14
2    OC002       C002   2019-04-14
3    OC003       C003   2019-04-14
```

**pg_package Table**

```
pg_order_id | plat_create_time | cm_sign_time
1                2019-04-14         2019-04-14
2                2019-04-14         2019-04-14
3                2019-04-14             -
```

**pg_send_package Table**

```
order_code | code | plat_create_time | lp_sign_time
OC001        C001   2019-04-14             -
OC002        C002   2019-04-14             -
OC003        C003   2019-04-14         2019-04-14
```

I need to count transaction data that have either 'cm_sign_time' or 'lp_sign_time'. The pg_package table need to be joined first to pg_order, after that it can be joined to deli_order table.

First I try to join the pg_send_package table with deli_order table first. This is my query

```
SELECT 
    DATE(A.create_time) AS 'Create Time',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN B.lp_sign_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Completed Order'
FROM
    deli_order A
INNER JOIN pg_send_package B ON B.order_code = A.order_code AND B.code = A.code
WHERE DATE(A.plat_create_time) = '2019-04-14'
GROUP BY DATE(A.plat_create_time);
```

and the result

```
Create Time | Completed Order
2019-04-14     130
```

But when I join the other 2 table, the result i got is nothing. This is my query

```
SELECT 
    DATE(A.plat_create_time) AS 'Create Time',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN B.lp_sign_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN D.cm_sign_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Completed Order'
FROM
    deli_order A
INNER JOIN pg_send_package B ON B.order_code = A.order_code AND B.code = A.code
INNER JOIN pg_order C ON C.order_code = A.order_code AND C.oms_code = A.code
INNER JOIN pg_package D ON D.pg_order_id = C.id
WHERE
    DATE(A.plat_create_time) = '2019-04-14'
GROUP BY DATE(A.plat_create_time);
```

This is the result

```
Create Time | Completed Order
```

I need to sum the count result from transaction that have either 'lp_sign_time' or 'cm_sign_time' on it.

My expected result is

```
Create Time | Completed Order
2019-04-14        150
```

150 is came from 130 transactions with 'lp_sign_time' and 20 transactions with 'cm_sign_time' 
What should i change in my query?

Comment: Good example how MySQL questions should be written also it also shows you did your own effort and research to solve it.. + 1 for that for sure.  But you forgot one thing can you add the expected results based on the example data as well?

Comment: @RaymondNijland ah, im sorry, i will edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` combine `pg_send_package` and  `pg_package` table make a result set for `order_code,code,lp_sign_time` then do `OUTER JOIN` with `COUNT`.

```
SELECT DATE(A.plat_create_time) AS 'Create Time', 
       COUNT(lp_sign_time) AS 'Completed Order'
FROM deli_order A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT order_code, 
           code, 
           lp_sign_time
    FROM pg_send_package psp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.order_code, 
           C.code, 
           pp.cm_sign_time
    FROM pg_package pp
         INNER JOIN pg_order C ON pp.pg_order_id = C.id
) t1 ON t1.order_code = A.order_code
        AND t1.code = A.code
        AND DATE(A.plat_create_time) = '2019-04-14'
GROUP BY DATE(A.plat_create_time);
```

Comment: Im sorry, I think i got it wrong when i put the data for pg_package table. There is no 'order_code' and 'code' in there. I already edit the question so please can you take a look again

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo Hi I had  edited my answer just select column from `pg_order`

Comment: Thank you so much! Your query works perfectly! I've been dealing with this for hours because my limited knowledge